# How to make the bash for loop exit?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm new to bash programming and I was wondering how to exit from the bash loop once it's done executing the statements.

I'm trying to create a ping script and it works .. but the script doesn't exit. Say the last host address is 192.168.42.18.. the script doesn't exit after that. It just stuck trying to iterate.

As I said Ilm new so I'm sorry for my noobness xD

I have tried 2 methods and both the methods end up in not exiting after the statements get executed.

Method 1

```
for ((x=42;x<=43;x++))
do
    for ((y=1;y<=20;y++))
    do
        ping -c 1 192.168.$x.$y | grep "bytes from" |cut -d " " -f 4|cut -d":" -f 1 &
    done
done
```

Method 2

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in {42..43}
do
    for h in {1..100}
    do
        ping -c 1 192.168.$n.$h | grep "bytes from" |cut -d " " -f4 | cut -d ":" -f1 &
    done
done
```

Kindly shed some light on how I should proceed further.

Comment: last address is 43.20, why do you think it should be 42.18?  What is the condition for loop termination?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. For loops *do* exit after the last iteration. What, exactly, are you seeing?

Comment: I recommend you avoid backgrounding your pipelines.  It's liable to spawn more processes than you should probably be handling, and makes it difficult to debug things.  What *looks* like `.18` being the last line processed might just be `.18` being the list line to *finish* processing. See if the script runs without the `&` at the end of the pipes.  Also, investigate [`fping`](http://fping.org/) as an alternative; it's probably available for your linux distro.

Comment: @triplee .. if i remove a bracket from the for loop of the first method i get a syntax error..

Comment: @karaka .. well i just need the script to exit after the last alive host is found. but its not..

Comment: @karakfa, stating your actual goal up front is a great way to improve your question. If we know where you're trying to go, we can direct you better.  Read abouy [XY Problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @ghoti.. i will have a look at fping but if i remove the & wouldnt that make my script slow... will give a try on what you have suggested and will reply back

Comment: Method 2 seems to be working fine for me, when you say it stays stuck trying to iterate, you mean in one of the loops?

Comment: @ghoti it works if i dont background my pipes.. but is there anyother way to improve the performance of the script. imagine if i had to scan a whole class b subnet (for example) that would have like ages to get over even though the ping count is 1... so any other improvements which can be done ?

Comment: Feel free to edit the code in the question, obviously; I simply lifted the pastebin scripts you linked to. The first one does indeed seem to have a syntax error, as also pointed out in @GlennJackman's answer.

Comment: @Krishna, imaging if you're backgrounding the piped command lines for 254 IPs in 256 netblocks.  65000-odd pipelines with 4 processes each.  And how big is the process table in your system?  I'll tell you.  *Not that big*.  :-)  If you're going to background things, *you must keep track of them*, and that adds complexity to your script.  `fping` is likely the solution to your problem, even though it's not the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You start a large number of  background processes inside the loops. They  continue to run even after the loops have finished.

Can we  assume that you put the `&`  there on purpose? If you don't want the jobs to run in the background, take it out.

As it is, the  failed ping processes should finish in a few seconds, maybe a minute tops (depending on the version of `ping` and somewhat on your network).

Comment: yes the & was there on purpose so that i can speed up the script... if i remove the & it works fine as expected .. And can you suggest me on how to improve the script which i have written for better performance. That was a sample code. if i had to do the same on a very high number of hosts, the code will take hell lot of time to complete.. is there any other method which i can look on ?

Answer (score 1):

C-style for loops need to use *double* parentheses in bash

```
for ((x=42;x<=43;x++))
```

This is because bash needs special syntax for arithmetic operations.

Refs: [`for`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-for), [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) (scroll down a bit for `((...))`)

Comment: Yes . im using double parenthesis.. but im still waiting for the response from tripleee on why the parenthesis was removed because it throws me a syntax error.

Comment: He just brought over your code from the pastebins, where you do not have double parens.